# Django CSS problems with SVG map

Tags: html, css, django

I have the following html with an svg: [html code](https://pastebin.pl/view/08fbd3dc)

and the following CSS:

```
body{
    background-color: rgb(162, 190, 199);
}

.mapdiv{
    width:28%;
    margin: auto;
}

.mapdiv path {
    fill: #e8e9d6;
    stroke: #000000;
    stroke-width:0.8px;
    transition: fill 0.3s;
}

.mapdiv :hover {
    fill:rgb(177, 38, 38);
}
```

Which looks like this: [image]

However when use the same code in django and load static like this:

```
{% load static %}
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>SVG Map</title>
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}">
</head>
```

The CSS work fine except for the :hover

```
.mapdiv :hover {
    fill:rgb(177, 38, 38);
}
```

[image]
Why?

Answer (score -1):

You just hover the div which is the svg tag parrent.

I think it should be:

```css
.mapdiv:hover path {
  fill:rgb(177, 38, 38);
}
```